# Gmail doesn't download some mail to POP client

Tags: download, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have set my Gmail to download all mail messages to my Outlook (2010) client. Some email (unfortunately, mostly important ones) don't seem to get downloaded. They are available in my Gmail Inbox, but I can't find them in Outlook. I have been using Outlook for a very long time (embarrassed to say just how long) and use to work in an Outlook support capacity.

Has anyone else seen this problem?

Comment: Try changing from POP to IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13291):

> If you're not using recent mode, ensure that the option to Leave messages on server in your POP client settings is not checked.
>
> Try enabling recent mode in your POP client by replacing username@gmail.com in the Username field of your POP client settings with recent:username@gmail.com, and enable Leave messages on server in your POP client settings.
>
> Recent mode fetches the last 30 days of mail, regardless of any other factors. If you don't check Leave messages on server, your messages will be moved to 'Trash' after download.
>
> Try deleting the entry for your Gmail address in your POP client and then re-adding it with all the correct settings. Please note that you may lose your local copy of any previously downloaded Gmail messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. After some thought and reading the POP configuration settings again and again, I figured out my problem. I had configured my email as POP on multiple devices (home computer, office computer, phone). So, if any mail was downloaded in any of the devices first, it would not download in outlook / windows mail.

Read this setting for POP Gmail configuration and it will work.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/47948